# Agregar una imagen de Background con Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

Estoy intentando agregar una imagen responsiva a esa sección  que ven en verde esmeralda `bg-primary`.

Estoy tratando de que el resultado final sea directamente una imagen o un video , en vez de que sea un color solido, les adjunto unas imágenes para que vean la sección del color solido y puedan ver la referencia en el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

--------------------------------------------------Código------------------------------------------------

```
    <header  class="masthead bg-primary text-white text-center "id="about">
        
        
       

        <div  class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column ">
            <!-- Masthead Avatar Image-->
            <img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="omoiavatar.png" alt="jpg" />
            <!-- Masthead Heading-->
            <h1 class="masthead-heading  mb-5">STUDIO OMOI</h1>
            
            <!---------------------------------------------------Masthead Subheading------------------------------------------------------------>
            <p class="masthead-subheading font-weight-light text-center ">illustrator | Motion Graphics | Concept</p>
        </div>
        
    </header>
```

**Github**

https://github.com/Batvizz/Portfolio

**Pagina** (para que puedan ver mejor la sección que les hablo)

https://batvizz.github.io/Portfolio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente hace falta ubicar `.container` y cambiarle el `backgroun-color` que tiene por el siguiente estilo:

```
.container {
 background-image: url(../img/Selfie.jpg);
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-position: center top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Es cuestión de adaptar tu img: **URL** y **size** y **position**.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta , donde podría ubicar .container ? tendría que navegar los mi archivo css ?

Comment: Claro. En tu CSS.

Comment: Estaba viendo en GitHub el archivo **styles.css**, y en la línea 542 comienza **.container**. Es mejor agregar el estilo completo después de éste, así como en mi respuesta, para que no te compliques...

Comment: Gracias por el codigo y por decime en que linea estaba , trate de agregar el codigo como me dijistes y funciono de cierta manera pero no solo se cambia ese fondo sino que se cambian otros containers que tengo

Comment: ojala pudiera adjuntarte una foto

Comment: En ese caso, simplemente crea una nueva clase: en tu HTML, donde está ```<div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column"</div>```, y con esa nueva clase crea tu nuevo estilo. Por ejemplo: ```<div class=container mi-background"</div>``` luego el estilo: ```.mi-background { background-image: url( ... ); }```

Comment: Voy a intentar eso Narciso , yo la verdad pense que en la pagina toda la parte esmeralda que era el Header directamente se podía poner entre su clase una imagen como background , como este ejemplo

Comment: Gracias Narciso , Justamente con la segunda respuesta pude lograr lo que intentaba hacer , la otra pregunta que capas sea un poco tonta , si quiero llegar a saber las dimensiones del header al que le estoy aplicando la imagen , lo pregunto por que a la hora de buscar una imagen para poder redimensionar una para que calze justo

Comment: No es necesario saber las dimensiones, porque en cada dispositivo, móvil, tablet y pc, son diferentes. Y ¿Qué agregar al header? Una imagen en un div contenedor, o como background? Explica más bien

Comment: <header  class="container-fluid  masthead bg-primary text-dark text-center container-new fondoinicio-background">

        </header>

Comment: estoy agregando mi background al class del header y la imagen si esta quedando como necesito , solo que se genera un patrón como de mosaicos con algunas otras imágenes

Comment: Sea cual sea la dimensión de la imagen, en su formato, no importa. Porque la imagen se adapta al su contenedor con ```100%``` de ancho total. Si el header es de ```100%``` de ancho, a la imagen se le da también ```100%``` de ancho para que cubra todo

Comment: Para solucionar el mosaico (se repite la imagen), agrega: ```background-repeat: no-repeat``` para que no se repita

Comment: Gracias Narciso pude dejar la imagen bien acomodada , estuve experimentando y probando , utilice este en mi background de CSS background-repeat: no-repeat;
                          background-size:cover;

Comment: Mi ultima duda es sobre esta linea de codigo background-image: url(https://)

Comment: Si quisiera utilizar una imagen dentro de mi repositorio , no tendría que utilizar una sintaxis diferente en vez de url , por ejemplo background-image:"imagen.jpg"; ?

Comment: Oh, y quedó muy atractivo .  Peeeeeeeeero, hay otro problema. Revisa tu página con un teléfono, y fíjate que el contenedor donde están los vídeos, o los vídeos mismo en la vista móvil no es legible. Dale al vídeo un ancho de 100% (**en @media (min-width: 576px)** en la línea 4494. Prueba eso

Comment: No importa donde esté tu img. Siempre debe ser ```background-image: url()```. Si está en la misma carpeta, la URL es así: ```url(img/mi foto.jpg)```. Y si está una carpeta anterior, es: ```url(../img/mi foto.jpg```. y si está en GitHub u otro lado, en internet, es: ```url(www.miFoto.jpg)```. Espero que entiendas

Comment: si lo entendí , narciso gracias por la ayuda

Comment: gracias por lo de atractivo :) , si en la sección de "Animacion 2D"  estaba tratando de agregar unas cajas como las imágenes , pero en vez de que sean las imágenes estaba intentando que sean videos , pero me di cuenta que no son responsivos , no se adaptan al cambio de tamaño , pero bueno esa es otra odisea que tengo que pasar jejej